# Enum - type of a specific interface without implementing it

Tags: java, enums

I need to use an Enum from an external library in my api and i need that enum to implement an interface. As I am not able to modify the Enum from the library to implement a specific interface, i am wondering if it is an option to do the following (it's a basic example):

Enum from library:

```
public enum ExampleEnumType {

    private long id;
    private String description;

    public long getId() {
       return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
       return description;
    }
}
```

What i would need is to implement the interface, but i am not able to:

```
public enum ExampleEnumType implements ExampleInterface {
    private long id;
    private String description;

    public long getId() {
       return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
       return description;
    }
    @Override
    public ExampleObject createExampleObject() {
      return new ExampleObject(getId(), getDescription());
    }
}
```

I need the values from enum to be of type ExampleInterface (as implementing the interface) to use them in a method:

```
public List<ExampleInterface> getStaticData() {
    List<ExampleInterface> examples = Lists.newLinkedList();
    examples.addAll(Arrays.asList(ExampleEnumType.values()));
    //more code
    return examples;
}
```

What i was thinking is doing the following, but i am not sure if it is an option:

```
public List<ExampleInterface> getExampleObjects() {
return
    Arrays.stream(ExampleEnumType.values()).<ExampleInterface>map(
        exampleEnumType -> () -> {
            return new ExampleObject(exampleEnumType.getId(), exampleEnumType.getDescription());
        }).collect(toList());
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: of course the first snippet works, you just create N anonymous `Runnable` classes with no relation to `EnumType`. It is unclear (to me) what you are actual goal is.

Comment: @luk2302 I updated the question. The goal is to use the enum as being of type ExampleInterface and i have no clue on how to that otherwise.

Comment: This Question is not clear. For one thing, you don’t explain where ID and description come from. I suggest you rewrite your example with some contrived specific scenario.

Comment: @BasilBourque I updated the question, hopefully now it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always **feature composition over inheritance**:

```java
public enum ExampleEnumTypeExampleInterfaceAdapter implements ExampleInterface {

    private static final Map<ExampleEnumType,ExampleEnumTypeExampleInterfaceAdapter> adapters=Collections.synchronizedMap(new EnumMap<>(ExampleEnumType.class));

    private ExampleEnumType exampleEnumType;
    private ExampleEnumTypeExampleInterfaceAdapter(ExampleEnumType en){
        this.exampleEnumType=en;
    }
    public static ExampleEnumTypeExampleInterfaceAdapter getAdapter(ExampleEnumType en){
        return adapters.computeIfAbsent(en,ExampleEnumTypeExampleInterfaceAdapter::new);
    }
    @Override
    public ExampleObject createExampleObject() {
      return new ExampleObject(en.getId(), en.getDescription());
    }

    public ExampleEnumType getEnum(){
        return exampleEnumType;
    }
}
```

This creates a new class implementing `ExampleInterface`. For every instance of the enum, you have a corresponding instance of the class.

If you want to get the implementation of the interface for an enum constant, use `ExampleEnumTypeExampleInterfaceAdapter.getAdapter(ExampleEnumType.ENUM_CONSTANT)`.

In order to get the enum from a `ExampleEnumTypeExampleInterfaceAdapter` object, use `yourAdapterObject.getEnum()`